# RESTful method for representing a has_one relationship with no identifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, entity-attribute-value

I currently have a service with a REST API which is pretty standard:

```
show: GET /users/1
update: PUT /users/1
```

...and some has_many relationships which follow the same convention:

```
show: GET /users/1/friends/1
update: PUT /users/1/friends/1
```

However, there is also an EAV table to handle settings (sorry, this part isn't going to change), set up to act as a has_one relationship. Internally:

```
user.settings # returns {:sound => true, :tutorials => true}
user.update_settings # expects {:sound => false}
```

It works well locally, but there's no ID to represent it the way the other routes work. Instead, the routes could be set up like this:

```
show: GET /users/1/settings
update: PUT /users/1/settings
```

Is this a normal way to handle this, or is there some other convention I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you do not need an Id to access the settings, why not treat it as an attribute of the collection? Internally it's the same to you, just close the `/users/:id/settings` endpoint. And `GET` and `UPDATE` the user resource to change settings. The user would look somthing like this:

```
{ "id" : 12,
 "settings": {
...
 }
}
```

If you think of settings an attribute, the enpoint does not seem grammatically correct. Imagine you posed the same question regarding age of the user. Would you open a /user/:id/age endpoint? Is it all that the settings has more attributes? where to stop then? Again a matter of concepts and above all CONSISTENCY.

But don't be a REStafarian. Your approach is also good. For me is much more a matter of consistency so that you dont have to write tons of doc for your developers explaining exceptions. So make your choice taking into account what fits best with the rest (i'd go for my suggestion).

Be pragmatic!